# Call function as string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function

I am trying to call a function from another view controller with `NSSelectorFromString`. I have tried this:

```
MainScreenViewController().perform(NSSelectorFromString("function"))
```

But the application crashes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using swift 4?

Comment: Yes it is indeed swift 4

Comment: add @ojc as below answer, this is required from swift 4.

Comment: The `perform selector` pattern with string argument and `NSSelectorFromString` is very *objective-c-ish*. There are better (and more reliable) ways in Swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add an `@objc` inference to the function, otherwise your function will not be expressable in Objective-C, which is what `NSSelectorFromString` uses.

```
@objc func function() {
    [...]
}
```

Learn more about the limited `@objc` inference in Swift 4 [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0160-objc-inference.md).

Comment: Are you missing the `()`?